# How to get errors message with Laravel 4 using Ardent

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel 4, and I took a look at Ardent. It seems to be a really good package for speed with validation. So I understand how to set the rules and insert data to my database but I still cannot find a way to display the error messages when the validations fail.

```
$comment = new Post_comment();
$comment->id_poster = Input::get('id_poster');
$comment->like = "ciao";
$comment->text = Input::get('text');
$comment->id_post = Input::get('post_id');
if ($comment->save()) {
    $status = "success";
} else {
    $status =  $comment->Ardent->errors()->all(); // this not working
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the `->Ardent` segment:

`$status = $comment->errors()->all();`

Since Ardent extends Eloquent, you don't need to access it that way, all its functionality is in the original class. I guess that you are using that because you followed the package's documentation literally, but when it says

> Retrieve all validation errors with **Ardent->errors()->all()**. Retrieve
>   errors for a specific attribute using
>   **Ardent->validationErrors->get('attribute')**.

it really means that you should replace `Ardent` with your model instance.